# Using Uppy in TypeScript Webcomponent

Tags: typescript, web-component, lit-element, lit, uppy

I'm trying to integrate [uppy](https://uppy.io/) into a webcomponent. I created a fresh typescript project using `@open-wc`: `npm init @open-wc --destinationPath C:\service-ui --type scaffold --scaffoldType app --features  --typescript true --tagName service-ui --writeToDisk true --installDependencies npm`

I added the uppy dependencies and imported exactly as pointed out in the getting started guide from uppy. Nevertheless, the app does not run: `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../node_modules/@uppy/dashboard/lib/index.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at UploadUi.ts:6:8)`.

[I created a repo with my code](https://github.com/HerrDietz/lit-uppy-example). I not very familiar with the different module systems. What am I doing wrong?